# How can I pass JavaScript variables to my CSS3 animations?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got an animation like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideImg0
    0%
        background-position: center 0px
    40%
        background-position: center -50px
    55%
        background-position: center 50px
    75%
        background-position: center 500px
    85%
        background-position: center 510px
    100%
        background-position: center 500px
```

But I need this animation to be slightly different for 4 different images. At the moment I've got slideImg1 (which is exactly the same but everything pixel value is +500), slideImg2 and slideImg2. Waste of time/space, and not very maintainable.

Is there any way that I can pass a value from JavaScript to alter this? So that I can go "Run slideImg with all values +500px"? Instead of

```
$(".heroImgWrapper").css("-webkit-animation", "slideImg" +counter + " 1s linear");
```

Comment: CSS3 is much faster. There's a fair amount of animation going on and I don't want it to slow down older computers.

Comment: I've found JQuery animations very slow on mobile. I'd really prefer to use CSS3.

Comment: +1 for refusing to use jQuery for non-essential cosmetic details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a `transition` instead of an animation, like so:

```
transition:background-position 1s cubic-bezier(0,-1,0.8,1.3);
```

Adjust the numbers as needed, but basically a curve with control points outside the 0-1 range will produce a bounce effect like your animation seems to be trying to create. With this strategy, you can adjust the position as needed and let the transition do the work.

EDIT: You will need `-webkit-transition` as well, of course. Also, see http://cubic-bezier.com/ to design a suitable curve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use, just pass in your selector and desired delta:

```
function setCss(selector, delta) {
    var points = {
        0: 0,
        40: 55,
        55: 50,
        75: 500,
        85: 510,
        100: 500
    };
    if (typeof delta === "undefined") delta = 0;

    var newPoints = {};
    for (key in points) {
        newPoints[key] = points[key] + delta;
    }

    for (key in newPoints) {
        // Write your code here 
    }
}
```